# JS/Dr. Strange's portal animation cannot be positioned on the outer frame of the circle behind the cards if only the cards are turned behind them

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, p5.js

**The part containing the card rotation and portal code:**

```
</script>

<script>
//sound effect
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flipSound = document.getElementById("flipSound");

  $(".card").click(function() {
    var card = $(this);

    // Check if the card is not already flipping to avoid multiple flips
    if (!card.hasClass('flipping')) {
      card.addClass('flipping');

      // Check if the front side is facing the viewer
      if (!card.hasClass("flipped")) {
        flipSound.currentTime = 0; // Reset the audio to the start
        flipSound.play();
        startAnimation(); 
        console.log("started")
        card.addClass("flipped");
        } else {
            
            stopAnimation(); 
            console.log("stopped")
            card.removeClass("flipped");
        }
        

      setTimeout(function() {
        card.removeClass('flipping');
      }, 1000); // Adjust the timeout to match your animation duration
    }
  });

  // Prevent sound on back side click
  $(".card__back").click(function(e) {
 
    e.stopPropagation();

  });
});


</script>


<script>
    // Body hoover effect
    document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        document.body.classList.add("hoverEffect");
    });

    document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        document.body.classList.remove("hoverEffect");
    });
</script>


<script>
// portal effect
var p5Instance;
function startAnimation() {

   

    const sketch = (p) => {

        const createParticleSystem = (location) => {
            const origin = location.copy();
            const particles = [];
            const addParticle = velocity => {
                const rand = p.random(0, 1);
                if (rand <= .3) {
                    particles.push(createSparkParticle(origin, velocity.copy()));
                } else {
                    particles.push(createParticle(origin, velocity.copy()));
                }
            };
            const applyForce = force => {
                particles.forEach(particle => {
                    particle.applyForce(force);
                });
            };
            const run = () => {
                particles.forEach((particle, index) => {
                    particle.move();
                    particle.draw();

                    if (particle.isDead()) {
                        particles.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
            };
            return {
                origin,
                addParticle,
                run,
                applyForce
            };
        };

        const createSparkParticle = (locationP, velocity) => {
            const particle = createParticle(locationP, velocity);
            let fade = 255;
            const draw = () => {
                p.colorMode(p.HSB);
                p.stroke(16, 62, 100, fade);
                const arrow = velocity.copy().normalize().mult(p.random(2, 4));
                const direction = p5.Vector.add(particle.location, arrow);
                p.line(particle.location.x, particle.location.y, direction.x, direction.y);
            };
            const move = () => {
                particle.applyForce(p.createVector(p.random(-.2, .2), p.random(-0.1, -0.4)));
                particle.velocity.add(particle.acc);
                particle.location.add(particle.velocity.copy().normalize().mult(p.random(2, 4)));
                particle.acc.mult(0);
                fade -= 5;
            };
            return {
                ...particle,
                draw,
                move
            }
        }

        const createParticle = (locationP, velocity) => {
            const acc = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const location = locationP.copy();
            let fade = 255;
            const fadeMinus = p.randomGaussian(15, 2);
            let ligther = 100;
            let situate = 62;
            const draw = () => {
                p.colorMode(p.HSB)
                p.stroke(16, p.constrain(situate, 62, 92), p.constrain(ligther, 60, 100), fade);
                const arrow = velocity.copy().mult(2);
                const direction = p5.Vector.add(location, arrow);
                p.line(location.x, location.y, direction.x, direction.y);
            };
            const move = () => {
                velocity.add(acc);
                location.add(velocity.copy().div(p.map(velocity.mag(), 18, 0, 5, 1)));
                acc.mult(0);
                fade -= fadeMinus;
                ligther -= 8;
                situate += 8;
            };
            const applyForce = force => {
                acc.add(force);
            };
            const isDead = () => {
                if (fade < 0 || location.x < 0 || location.x > p.width || location.y > p.height) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            return {
                draw,
                move,
                applyForce,
                isDead,
                velocity,
                location,
                acc
            };
        };

        const createMover = () => {
            const location = p.createVector(p.width / 2, p.height / 2);
            const velocity = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const acc = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const mass = 10;
            let angle = 0;
            let angleVelocity = 0;
            let angleAcc = 0;
            let len = 100;
            const particleSystems = [
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location)
            ];
            const getGotoVector = angle => {
                const radius = p.map(angleVelocity, 0, 0.3, 0, 55);
                const goToVector = p.createVector(
                    location.x + radius * p.cos(angle),
                    location.y + radius * p.sin(angle)
                );
                return goToVector;
            };
            const draw = () => {
                const goToVector = getGotoVector(angle);
                particleSystems.forEach(particleSystem => {
                    particleSystem.run();
                });
            };
            const renderParticleSystem = () => {
                particleSystems.forEach(particleSystem => {
                    const goToVector = getGotoVector(angle - p.random(0, p.TWO_PI));
                    const prepencular = p.createVector(
                     (goToVector.y - location.y)*-1,
                    (goToVector.x - location.x)
                    );
                    prepencular.normalize();
                    prepencular.mult(angleVelocity * 70);
                    particleSystem.origin.set(goToVector);
                    particleSystem.addParticle(prepencular);
                    const gravity = p.createVector(0, 0.3);
                    particleSystem.applyForce(gravity);
                });
            };
            const move = () => {
              
                angleAcc = 0.005;
                angleVelocity = p.constrain(angleVelocity + angleAcc, 0, 0.32);
                angle += angleVelocity;
                angleAcc = 0;
                renderParticleSystem();
            };
            return {
                draw,
                move
            };
        };

        let mover;

        p.setup = function() {
            p.createCanvas(240, 320);
            p.clear(); 
            mover = createMover();
        }

        p.draw = function() {
            p.clear();
            mover.move();
            mover.draw();
        }
    };

    p5Instance = new p5(sketch);
}

// stop animation

function stopAnimation() {
    if (p5Instance) {
        p5Instance.remove();
        p5Instance = null;
    }
}

</script>
```

Hello friends,
I have 6 cards that can turn around. When one of the cards turns around, I want the Portal animation to appear in the outermost frame of the colored circles on the back of the cards. How can I achieve this in my code?

### ***What to do for each of the 6 cards***

[image]

- **main file (including portal animation):**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1famaPF_Rz-CIjbiBCOlIFZH-LWKjlpv_/view?usp=sharing

- **aplication's demo link with portal (not working properly):**

https://tm-game-cards-portal.netlify.app/

---

- **aplication's demo link without portal:**

https://tm-game-cards-v02.netlify.app/

- **main file (not including portal animation):**
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fKABYycS1cfBZ7GWYHueSXkH_XnLZZpa/view

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In summary, a portal was not created in an area other than the cards and the page was loaded completely. A flag was added to prevent the animation from starting over and over again.

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"> 
  <title>Game Cards App</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/entertainment-events-hobbies/24/card-game-cards-hold-512.png">
</head>


<audio id="flipSound" preload="auto">
  <source src="C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\card\flip-sound.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>

<body>
  <div class="tm-container">
    <div class="tm-letter" id="t-letter">T</div>
    <div class="tm-letter" id="m-letter">M</div>
  </div>
</body>




<main>

  
   <div id="gameCardLink">Game Cards</div>
  <p><a href="https://github.com/murattasci06"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></p>
</main>


<ul>
  <li class="card" >
    <div class="card__flipper">
      <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://gecbunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Spiderman-No-Way-Home.jpg" alt="Spiderman">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Spiderman</p>
        <p class="card__num">1</p>
      </div>
  
      
      <iframe class="frame" 
      width="225"
      height="340"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfVOs4VSpmA?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
      title="YouTube video player"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
      allowfullscreen
      ></iframe>

      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#514d9b" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>1.89 Bil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 
 
 
  
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
         <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1e/f1/3d/1ef13dfa4b7b8c131302e242d1ec48d7.jpg" alt="Batman">
         <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Batman</p>
        <p class="card__num">2</p>
      </div>
      
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mqqft2x_Aa4?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>

      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#35a541" stroke-width="35"/>
        </svg>
        <span>771 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelcinematicuniverse/images/1/18/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._3_soundtrack_album.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20230510223849" alt="Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3</p>
        <p class="card__num">3</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u3V5KDHRQvk?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#bdb235" stroke-width="35"/>
        </svg>
        <span>845.4 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
       <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/8940499.jpg" alt="Shazam">
        <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Shazam2</p>
        <p class="card__num">4</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AIc671o9yCI?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#db6623" stroke-width="35"/>
        </svg>
        <span>462.5 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/131/1316679.jpeg" alt="Flash">
        <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Flash</p>
        <p class="card__num">5</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hebWYacbdvc?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#3e5eb3" stroke-width="35"/>
        </svg>
        <span>560.2 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src=" https://images3.alphacoders.com/121/1213553.jpg" alt="Dr_Strange_2">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Dr_Strange_2</p>
        <p class="card__num">6</p>
         </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aWzlQ2N6qqg?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#aa9e5c" stroke-width="35"/>
        </svg>
        <span>955.8 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="loading-animation">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>




<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(48, 48, 48, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  animation: shine 2s linear infinite;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(33.33% - 30px + 9.999px);
  height: 340px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  perspective: 1000;
 
}
.card:first-child .card__front {
  background:#5271C2;
}

.card__front img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}



.card:first-child .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(52, 78, 147, 0.8)
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__front {
  background:#35a541;
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(34, 107, 42, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__front {
  background: #bdb235;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(129, 122, 36, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__front {
  background: #db6623;
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(153, 71, 24, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__front {
  background: #3e5eb3;
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(42, 64, 122, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__front {
  background: #aa9e5c;
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(122, 113, 64, 0.8);
}
.card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card__flipper {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.card__front, .card__back {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
}
.card__front {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card__back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
  background: #141414;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.card__back span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.card__name {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.card__name span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.card__num {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card__num {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .card .card__front,
  .card .card__back {
    height: 290px;
  }
}

/* Demo */
main {
  text-align: center;
}
main h1, main p {
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}
main h1 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.fa-github {
  color: white; 
  font-size: 50px;
}

.tm-letter {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: letter-animation 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes letter-animation {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  10%, 40%, 60%, 90% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  20%, 80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

#m-letter {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
     background: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 46%, rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.9) 54%, transparent 57%); 
   
    filter: blur(4px) brightness(1.5); 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
    transform: scale(0.9); 
    z-index: -1;
}

a:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.3); 
}


body.hoverEffect {
      background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #000000, #000033, #000066, #1a1a1a);
}

#gameCard { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 
    0 0 50px 10px #FFD700,  
    0 0 100px 20px #0000FF, 
    0 0 150px 30px #000033; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
    color: #FFD700;  
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #FFD700; 
}




#loading-animation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.loader {
  border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 8px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}



</style>


<script>
var Flipper = (function() {
  var card = $('.card');
  var flipper = card.find('.card__flipper');
  var win = $(window);
  
  var flip = function() {
    var thisCard = $(this);
    var thisFlipper = thisCard.find('.card__flipper');
    var offset = thisCard.offset();
    var xc = win.width() / 2;
    var yc = win.height() / 2;
    var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    var cardW = thisCard.outerWidth() / 2;
    var cardH = thisCard.height() / 2;

    var transX = xc - offset.left - cardW;
    var transY = docScroll + yc - offset.top - cardH;
//     if (offset.top > card.height()) transY = docScroll - offset.top + cardH;
    if (win.width() <= 700) transY = 0;
    
    if (card.hasClass('active')) unflip();
        
    thisCard.css({'z-index': '3'}).addClass('active');
    
    thisFlipper.css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)'
    }).addClass('active');
    
    
    
    
    return false;
  };
  
  var unflip = function(e) {
    card.css({'z-index': '1'}).removeClass('active');
    flipper.css({
      'transform': 'none',
      '-webkit-transform': 'none',
      '-ms-transform': 'none'
    }).removeClass('active');
  };
  
  var bindActions = function() {
    card.on('click', flip);
    win.on('click', unflip);
  }
  
  var init = function() {
    bindActions();
  };
  
  return {
    init: init
  };
  
}());
Flipper.init();
  
</script>



<script>
<!-- HOOVER FOR TRAILER -->

let hoverTimeout;

$('.card').hover(function() {
    const currentCard = $(this); // Store the current card element in a variable

    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        currentCard.find('.card__front').hide();
        currentCard.find('.iframe').show();
        var src = currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src");
        currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src", src);

        // Add fullscreen functionality
        currentCard.find('.iframe').on('click', function() {
            $(this).requestFullscreen();
        });

    }, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)

}, function() {
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); // Clear the timeout to prevent actions if the user moves away before 5 seconds

    $(this).find('.card__front').show();
    $(this).find('.iframe').hide();
    var src = $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src");
    $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src", src.replace('?autoplay=1', ''));
});



</script>

<script>
var cardFlags = {}; // An object to store card flags (NEW)

$(document).ready(function() {
  var flipSound = document.getElementById("flipSound");

  $(".card").click(function() {
    var card = $(this);
    var cardId = card.find(".card__num").text();
    console.log(cardId);

    
    if (!card.hasClass('flipping')) {
      card.addClass('flipping');

      // Check if the front side is facing the viewer
      if (!card.hasClass("flipped")) {
        flipSound.currentTime = 0; 
        flipSound.play();
        console.log("is card flag true or false", cardId);

        if (!cardFlags[cardId]) {
          startAnimation(div); 
          console.log("started");
          cardFlags[cardId] = true; 
          card.addClass("flipped");
        }
        
        // adding canvas to back-side (NEW)
        var div = document.querySelector('.flipped .card__flipper.active .card__back');
        var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('p5Canvas')[0];
        if (div && canvas) {
          div.appendChild(canvas);
          canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
        }
      } else {
       
        console.log("stopped");
        card.removeClass("flipped");
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        card.removeClass('flipping');
      }, 1000); // Adjust the timeout to match your animation duration
    }
  });

 
  $(".card__back").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});







</script>


<script>
    // Body hoover effect
    document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        document.body.classList.add("hoverEffect");
    });

    document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        document.body.classList.remove("hoverEffect");
    });
</script>


<script>

// portal effect
var p5Instance;
function startAnimation(div) {
    // adding canvas to back-side (NEW)
    var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('p5Canvas')[0];
    if (div && canvas) {
        div.appendChild(canvas);
        canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
    }

    const sketch = (p) => {

        const createParticleSystem = (location) => {
            const origin = location.copy();
            const particles = [];
            const addParticle = velocity => {
                const rand = p.random(0, 1);
                if (rand <= .3) {
                    particles.push(createSparkParticle(origin, velocity.copy()));
                } else {
                    particles.push(createParticle(origin, velocity.copy()));
                }
            };
            const applyForce = force => {
                particles.forEach(particle => {
                    particle.applyForce(force);
                });
            };
            const run = () => {
                particles.forEach((particle, index) => {
                    particle.move();
                    particle.draw();

                    if (particle.isDead()) {
                        particles.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
            };
            return {
                origin,
                addParticle,
                run,
                applyForce
            };
        };

        const createSparkParticle = (locationP, velocity) => {
            const particle = createParticle(locationP, velocity);
            let fade = 255;
            const draw = () => {
                p.colorMode(p.HSB);
                p.stroke(16, 62, 100, fade);
                const arrow = velocity.copy().normalize().mult(p.random(2, 4));
                const direction = p5.Vector.add(particle.location, arrow);
                p.line(particle.location.x, particle.location.y, direction.x, direction.y);
            };
            const move = () => {
                particle.applyForce(p.createVector(p.random(-.2, .2), p.random(-0.1, -0.4)));
                particle.velocity.add(particle.acc);
                particle.location.add(particle.velocity.copy().normalize().mult(p.random(2, 4)));
                particle.acc.mult(0);
                fade -= 5;
            };
            return {
                ...particle,
                draw,
                move
            }
        }

        const createParticle = (locationP, velocity) => {
            const acc = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const location = locationP.copy();
            let fade = 255;
            const fadeMinus = p.randomGaussian(15, 2);
            let ligther = 100;
            let situate = 62;
            const draw = () => {
                p.colorMode(p.HSB)
                p.stroke(16, p.constrain(situate, 62, 92), p.constrain(ligther, 60, 100), fade);
                const arrow = velocity.copy().mult(2);
                const direction = p5.Vector.add(location, arrow);
                p.line(location.x, location.y, direction.x, direction.y);
            };
            const move = () => {
                velocity.add(acc);
                location.add(velocity.copy().div(p.map(velocity.mag(), 18, 0, 5, 1)));
                acc.mult(0);
                fade -= fadeMinus;
                ligther -= 8;
                situate += 8;
            };
            const applyForce = force => {
                acc.add(force);
            };
            const isDead = () => {
                if (fade < 0 || location.x < 0 || location.x > p.width || location.y > p.height) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            return {
                draw,
                move,
                applyForce,
                isDead,
                velocity,
                location,
                acc
            };
        };

        const createMover = () => {
            const location = p.createVector(p.width / 2, p.height / 2);
            const velocity = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const acc = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const mass = 10;
            let angle = 0;
            let angleVelocity = 0;
            let angleAcc = 0;
            let len = 100;
            const particleSystems = [
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location)
            ];
            const getGotoVector = angle => {
                const radius = p.map(angleVelocity, 0, 0.3, 0, 80);
                const goToVector = p.createVector(
                    location.x + radius * p.cos(angle),
                    location.y + radius * p.sin(angle)
                );
                return goToVector;
            };
            const draw = () => {
                const goToVector = getGotoVector(angle);
                particleSystems.forEach(particleSystem => {
                    particleSystem.run();
                });
            };
            const renderParticleSystem = () => {
                particleSystems.forEach(particleSystem => {
                    const goToVector = getGotoVector(angle - p.random(0, p.TWO_PI));
                    const prepencular = p.createVector(
                     (goToVector.y - location.y)*-1,
                    (goToVector.x - location.x)
                    );
                    prepencular.normalize();
                    prepencular.mult(angleVelocity * 70);
                    particleSystem.origin.set(goToVector);
                    particleSystem.addParticle(prepencular);
                    const gravity = p.createVector(0, 0.3);
                    particleSystem.applyForce(gravity);
                });
            };
            const move = () => {
              
                angleAcc = 0.005;
                angleVelocity = p.constrain(angleVelocity + angleAcc, 0, 0.32);
                angle += angleVelocity;
                angleAcc = 0;
                renderParticleSystem();
            };
            return {
                draw,
                move
            };
        };

        let mover;

        p.setup = function() {
            p.createCanvas(240, 320);
            p.clear(); 
            mover = createMover();
        }

        p.draw = function() {
            p.clear();
            mover.move();
            mover.draw();
        }
    };

    p5Instance = new p5(sketch);
}

// stop animation>>THERE'S NO NEED




</script>


<script>
// To hide the boot animation
function hideLoadingAnimation() {
  var loadingAnimation = document.getElementById("loading-animation");
  loadingAnimation.style.display = "none";
}


// Call hideLoadingAnimation() function when the page is fully loaded (NEW)
window.addEventListener("load", hideLoadingAnimation);

</script>  


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems more related to positioning which can be simply solved by proper CSS positioning. I am just experimenting with you code and with the following CSS, it will work

```
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 46.7%;
    top: 43%;
}
```

You can adjust the left and top positions according to your requirement

Comment: The animation overlaps as the cards are turned over and over again. This approach remains incomplete. It is also necessary to control whether the animation disappears or comes back with the flags. Even if the card turns itself over, the portal continues to appear problematic.

Comment: *Desired:*

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13an9aVphOnBH5gSMULpkfPNX8MSFq3-W/view?usp=sharing

*Undesired:*

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iHbrUuGYUPWkujc6E_y4SD4StlM1h70o/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

What a great concept!
You can have the canvas displaying on the back of the card by appending it as a child of the 'card__back' div and giving it `position: absolute` CSS.
something like:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.flipped .card__flipper.active .card__back');
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('p5Canvas')[0];
div.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
```

(The attached snippet would actually work if you run in the console of the provided demo https://tm-game-cards-portal.netlify.app/. Try it:))

Comment: https://tm-game-cards-portal.netlify.app/ Hello, this is not a demo of the working version. Can you update it with what you have done and a link to the entire corrected code please?

Comment: @murattaşçı as I wrote, this is a snippet that will make the required change on the provided demo site by executing it in the dev console (after clicking a card). I did not create a new snippet, as it is a minor DOM + CSS change.

Comment: the updated link: https://fantastic-alpaca-80c386.netlify.app 
updated code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1STVhMsQ5NRrY8H_cZXsqAgd5Ji-aPpHj/view?usp=sharing 
I added the approach you mentioned in the javascript code, but an extra portal is created at the beginning, and a portal is created on top of each other behind the cards. Sometimes portals do not appear behind cards. unfortunately I still haven't been able to make it consistent

Answer (score -1):

One way to achieve this is by creating a flag variable to keep track of whether the cards are flipped or not. When the cards are flipped back, you start the animation, and when they are flipped to the front, you stop the animation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Card Flip Animation</title>
<!-- Include any necessary libraries here, such as jQuery and p5.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"> 
</script>
<!-- Include your CSS styles here -->
<style>
    /* Your CSS styles for cards and animations here */
</style>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="flipSound" src="flip_sound.mp3"></audio>

<!-- Your HTML for the card here -->
<div class="card">Card Content</div>

<script>
    // Add a global variable to track the card flip state
    let cardFlipped = false;
    let p5Instance;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var flipSound = document.getElementById("flipSound");

        $(".card").click(function() {
            var card = $(this);

            if (!card.hasClass('flipping')) {
                card.addClass('flipping');

                if (!card.hasClass("flipped")) {
                    // Start animation and set the cardFlipped variable to 
    true
                    startAnimation();
                    cardFlipped = true;
                } else {
                    // Stop animation and set the cardFlipped variable to 
    false
                    stopAnimation();
                    cardFlipped = false;
                }

                setTimeout(function() {
                    card.removeClass('flipping');
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

        // Prevent sound on back side click
        $(".card__back").click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });

    // portal effect
    function startAnimation() {
        const sketch = (p) => {
            // Your p5.js animation code here
            // ...
        };

        p5Instance = new p5(sketch);
    }

    // stop animation
    function stopAnimation() {
        if (p5Instance) {
            p5Instance.remove();
            p5Instance = null;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, you have a cardFlipped variable that keeps track of the card's flip state. When the card is flipped back (cardFlipped is true), it starts the animation, and when the card is flipped to the front (cardFlipped is false), it stops the animation.

Comment: did it work? @murat taşçı

Comment: Could you update/delete your answer according to the question? I am waiting a demo which is working too.

Comment: why do you want me to delet it i dont understand is there something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
 `// ...
} else {
    stopAnimation();
    console.log("durduruldu");
    card.removeClass("flipped");
}
// ...

card.on("animationend", function() {
    stopAnimation();
    console.log("durduruldu");
});`
```